# Exchange online authentication with ADFS and C# console APP

Tags: c#, exchange-server, office365api, adfs3.0

I need to manipulate programmatically emails on exchange online mailbox from windows service APP. The company use ADFS based authentication to Office365 and exchange online. What is the best and easiest way to authenticate and get connection to a mailbox in this scenario? There are many posts and articles but they are very confusing. Any code examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After deeper investigation looks like best way to go is to use EWS - exchange web services https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900168(v=exchg.150).aspx . Works pretty well.